# ¿Cómo mostrar una fila y una columna de una matriz en python?

Tags: python, matriz

Mi objetivo es mostrar el pantalla una fila "**x**" y una columna "**y**" ingresada por teclado, de una matriz de cualquier orden, que contiene numeros generados de forma aleatoria, la idea es que de ser por ejemplo una matriz de 3x3, y de ingresar por teclado x=3 y además y=3, mostrar lo que corresponde(fila 2 y columna 2 de la matriz respectivamente, ya que la matriz comienza de 0 a 2 por ser **3x3**, fila 1 es fila 0, fila 2 es fila 1 y fila 2 es fila 3, igual con las columnas de la matriz), toda esta verificación ya está resuelta, el problema se encuentra en mostrar de forma correcta la fila y columna solicitada, es decir si tenemos por dar un ejemplo, la siguiente matriz generada tendría que tener la siguiente forma:

```
1   2   3
4   5   6
7   8   9
```

y si solicito por teclado , la fila 1, columna 3 (es decir fila 0 y columna 2):

```
1   2   3
        6
        9
```

Mi codigo es el siguiente:

```
import random
import os

def Mostrar():              #Todo este bloque funciona
    x=fila+1;y=columna+1    #Si queremos ver la fila 0 y columna 0, se debe ingresar fila 1 y columna 1
    while (x-1)<0 or x>=(fila+1) or (y-1)<0 or y>=(columna+1):
        x=int(input("X: "))     #se ingresa la fila a visualizar
        y=int(input("Y: "))     #se ingresa la columna a visualizar

        if (x-1)<0 or x>=(fila+1) or (y-1)<0 or y>=(columna+1):
            print("fila y columna invalida") 
        else:                       #Pero la matriz no se está mostrando adecuadamente
            for i in range(fila):
                for j in range(columna):
                    if (x-1)==i or (y-1)==j:
                        print(matriz[i][j],"\t", end=" ")
                    else:
                        print("\t")
                print()

fila=int(input("Fila: "))
columna=int(input("columna: "))
matriz = [ [ None for y in range( columna ) ] for x in range( fila ) ]
for i in range(fila):
    for j in range(columna):
        matriz[i][j]=random.randint(1,200)

Mostrar()
os.system("pause")
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sólo necesitas este pequeño cambio en tu rutina de impresión:

```
if (x-1)==i or (y-1)==j:
   print("%4d" % matriz[i][j], end=" ")
else:
   print("    ", end=" ")
```

Se trata simplemente de a) imprimir un valor si fila o columna es la deseada, o b) imprimir espacios en blanco para mantener todo alineado.

El formato de impresion `%4d` te garantiza ocupar cuatro posiciones por valor. Si no hay valor, entonces se imprimen cuatro espacios en el `else:`

Produce:

```
Filas: 4
columnas: 4
X: 2
Y: 4
                140 
  14   69   36   33 
                 22 
                190
```

y otra prueba:

```
Filas: 5
columnas: 7
X: 2
Y: 4
                 88                
 108  170  113  108  185  103  171 
                 71                
                 29                
                158
```